# Samba share on domain joined server

Tags: linux, active-directory, samba

I have a samba share which works fine with servers not joined to the domain. 
Now I want to have a similar samba share (RHEL7.7) which is accessible from domain joined servers (Windows)

The following is the samba config file.

```
[global]
    security = user
    workgroup = hello.world.sambashare.com
    realm = hello.world.sambashare.com
    netbios name = <server-name>
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 5000
    load printers = no
    map to guest = Bad user
    directory mask = 0777
[nfs]
    comment = NFS
    path = /nfs
    public = yes
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    writeable = yes
    browsable = yes
    create mask = 0777
```

I have a similar config file but only with `WORGROUP = WORKGROUP` when machines are not joined to the AD.

Both the share server and client are joined to the AD domain. The hostname of the samba share server is resolved from the client.

how is it possibel to share my folder when the servers are domain joined?

The samba share folder is a nfs mount point. But i m also not able to share any other folders.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a Unix machine joined to an AD domain, then start by reading this:
https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member

Then forget about sharing an NFS share, it never works correctly.

Comment: My UNIX machine is joined to the AD where i have samba configured. I m trying to access the samba share from a windows machine which is also joined to the same AD. So you say there is no way I can get such a setup working?

Comment: The smb.conf you posted is NOT for a domain joined machine, it is for a standalone server, if you want the machine to be a Unix domain member, you must set it up correctly and as you say you are using RHEL 7.7, you will be using Samba >= 4.8.0 this will mean that you cannot use sssd, If the share is a mounted NFS share, then these always give problems. Read the the link I posted and then set your smb.conf correctly.